# How does RequireJS know what module to load first?

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I'm trying to fathom RequireJS.

Most articles say that, if done properly then I should only need to reference the `require.js` file from my HTML page.

This code if taken from https://github.com/volojs/create-template and shows a hello world version.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script data-main="app" src="lib/require.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello World</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

In this example, how does RequireJS know to load the `app.js` file?  It's not defined anywhere?

Comment: In what way is this question 'Not about programming'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is - look at www / index.html

```
<script data-main="app" src="lib/require.js"></script>
```

`data-main` is the attribute that defines which file to load.

Comment: Ah... totally overlooked that!